# Getting a Horrible Frame Buffer In Ubuntu 16.04 Fix?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I recently started dual booting with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 16.04. Needless to say I ran into a TON of problems along the way... I was able to fix most of these problems with my good friend but theres just one that keeps stumping us. It seems to be some sort of frame buffer thats stopping my frames ever few seconds. Its extremely consistent and doesnt change. Heres my examples:

[Example 1](https://youtu.be/XgUvefLL3Rg)

[Example 2](https://youtu.be/yRh1Xrq78_g?t=53s)

I'm a beginner Ubuntu user and I really love to switch to Ubuntu completely and ditch Windows 7 but this is the one thing thats holding me back. This problem never occurred to me on Windows 7 which is why I feel like this is an Ubuntu problem. I've even tested the buffer on almost all resolutions and it appears on each one of them.

My Specs:

CPU: AMD FX6300

GPU: GeForce MSI GTX 970

RAM: 8GB

MB: GA-78LMT-USB3

Power: 650W

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Stronger

Comment: Did you install Nvidia drivers?

Comment: Yes I did http://imgur.com/a/Z6KJO

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the repository for the drivers where you can use the OpenSource drivers:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-370
```

You can also try through the Additional Drivers to choose the newest driver.

*On a side note, unless the game like on Steam is optimized for Linux, I have never been able to make the game play smoothly.  That is why I unfortunately keep Windows on my system as well.*

---

One thing you can try is to set the `GPU PowerMizer Mode` for NVIDIA to maximum.

To set this from command line type in the following:

```
nvidia-settings -a [gpu:0]/GpuPowerMizerMode=1
```

If that works for you, you can create a start up file that will launch this every time you reboot your system.

Create a file in your `~/.config/autostart` folder with a .desktop extension.  I called mine `~/.config/autostart/NVIDIAPower.desktop`

Add the following contents to the file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Name=NVIDIAPower
Comment=PowerMizer Mode Maximum
Exec=bash -c 'sleep 10 && /usr/bin/nvidia-settings -a [gpu:0]/GpuPowerMizerMode=1'
```

Set the proper permissions to the file:

```
sudo chmod 664 ~/.config/autostart/NVIDIAPower.desktop
```

Also set proper ownership for the file:

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER ~/.config/autostart/NVIDIAPower.desktop
```

When you reboot, the settings should be launched automatically.

This is what the `NVIDIA Settings` would look like.  I am running a GTX 560 Ti:

[image]

You can also try setting in OpenGL Settings for *Sync to VBlank* on

[image]

If you're running Steam Games, try turning off the Steam Overlay for In-Game.

[image]

Also try turning off Notifications for when Friends Join or when you receive messages. Also, maybe set the Flash Window when getting a message to *Never*.

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the response but sadly to no success... I will probably end up leaving that on though. Seems useful. Any other ideas?

Comment: @AidanStronger I added a few more suggestions that might help.  =)

Comment: No success... :( I already had VBlank on but I tried turning it off but still no results...

Comment: @AidanStronger I updated one more note at the top of my answer.

Comment: No luck :/ Do you think I clean reinstall of linux would help?

Comment: @AidanStronger Yeah, I guess you can try it.  Now that I think about it, mine at home is a clean install, but when you do the graphics card installation, use the PPA that I put in this answer.  I have better luck with them vs downloading the ones from NVIDIA.

Comment: @AidanStronger Sorry, one more update.  I added in the newest NVIDIA driver in my most recent edit.